# How to return the name of a column after mysql LIKE search

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to do a *google like* search function on my customer database.
so when you type you get drop down suggestions with the word u searched for **highlighted**.
i have 2 tables: 
**customers** and **addresses** (because some customers have multiple addresses)

here is the search query and it works perfectly:

```
$query = "
        SELECT id FROM 
        customer
        WHERE
        name LIKE :search OR
        surname LIKE :search OR
        email LIKE :search OR
        CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE :search
        UNION
        SELECT cust_id FROM 
        addresses
        WHERE
        CONCAT(address, ' ', town, ' ', postcode) LIKE :search


  ";
```

*:search* is obviously whats been searched for. It returns the customer id and from then i can display dropdown suggestions as they type. (done thru ajax)

What i am TRYING to achieve is rather than showing ALL the information(name surname email phone address town postcode etc) in the drop down suggestions, i would like to show The name and surname and whatever it is they are clearly searching for.

For example lets say on the database a customer is called:

Foo Bar.
tel: 0123456789
email: foo@bar.com

In the addresses table he has an address of 6 pack lane, petersville, EX23 6GH.

So as i type "**pack**" into the search field i want a drop down suggestion to come up with "**Foo Bar, 6 Pack Lane**"

But to do this i need to find out which *column* "**Pack**" refers to.

At the moment i am only returning the id because i dont know which piece of data is going to be searched for.

so is there a way of returning the **name** of the column that the **LIKE** query is returning?

many thanks

Comment: You could return all the columns (and compare client side, not too efficent), or use a `case`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: What if two columns match? What if all of them? I think its better to use `match(...) against(...) IN BOOLEAN MODE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html (requires full text index of columns being matched)

Comment: @chris85. yes i could do it client side. seems extremely long winded so i was wondering if there was an internal function. what do u mean use a case? thankyou

Comment: @Kisaragi if columns match it doesnt matter. i will list all results. and if they are from same customer i will make sure there are no duplicate id's. i dont know how to FTS and after some research i dont think its worth an FTS just to search small details.

Comment: A SQL case, I provided the link, take a look.